# Find a column where the identity column is breaking

Tags: sql

I have a table, e.g.

```
cust_ord_key 
1
2
3
4
5
7
9
```

How do I write a query to find out if the numbers are in sequence and not breaking anywhere?

Comment: what type of sql? (e..g oracle) & please provide sample data and expected result

Comment: identity columns should be treated as opaque blobs that just happen to fit in numeric columns. If you *care* about the numeric value, or about properties like "no gaps", I'd strongly suggest you're misusing them.

Comment: Use the `lag()` function. But in general the actual value of a generated unique identifier is completely meaningless. I agree with damien. There is absolutely no reason to check for gaps.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT SeqID AS MissingSeqID
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_id) SeqID from sys.columns) LkUp
LEFT JOIN dbo.TestData t ON t.ID = LkUp.SeqID
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like:

```
DECLARE @RESULT int;
SET @RESULT = 0;
DECLARE @FIRST_ID int;
DECLARE @LAST_ID int;
DECLARE @THIS_VALUE int;
DECLARE @NEXT_VALUE int;
SELECT @FIRST_ID = min(ID), @LAST_ID = max(ID) from table_name;

WHILE(@FIRST_ID <= @LAST_ID)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @THIS_VALUE = your_field_with_keys from table_name where ID = @FIRST_ID;
        SELECT @NEXT_VALUE = your_field_with_keys from table_name where ID = (@FIRST_ID + 1);
        if @THIS_VALUE > @NEXT_VALUE
            SET @RESULT = @FIRST_ID;
            --break your query here or do anything else
        SET @FIRST_ID = @FIRST_ID + 1;
    END
```

What does this query do? We declare @RESULT variable for taking an ID of key, where you key is breaking. @FIRST_ID and @LAST_ID are the minimal and maximal IDs from your table, we will use them later. @THIS_VALUE and @NEXT_VALUE are two variables for two keys to be compared.

Then we execute loop over our IDs. Then setting up @THIS_VALUE and @NEXT_VALUE with corresponding keys (this and the next). If @THIS_VALUE more than @NEXT_VALUE, it means that the key is breaking here (if previous key is more than next key), and we take the ID of element, where key is broken. And there you may stop your query or do some required logic.

Comment: Which dbms? Far from ANSI SQL. (And no one specified in question.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect, but definitely does the job, and is universal across all DB engines.

```
SELECT t1.id FROM myTable t1
LEFT JOIN myTable t2 ON t1.id+1 = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

When the identity doesn't break anywhere, this will only return the last entry. You can compensate for that with a procedural language, by first getting the `MAX(ID)` adding that to the `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE t2.id IS NULL AND t1.id<>5643
```

where `5643` is the max id (either a variable introduced in the query string, or can be a variable in the procedural SQL language of whatever DB engine you're using). The point is that it's the maximum value of the identity on that table.

OR, you can just dismiss the last row from the result set if you're doing it in PHP or whatever.